# How can I find both reference tables and referencial tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I find both reference tables and referencial  tables in Oracle SQL Developer using a simple script

Comment: You could use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

Comment: @EugenePodskal INFORMATION_SCHEMA is in PostgreSQL. Oracle stores static metadata in user_, all_, dba_ views and dynamic metadata in V$

Comment: As I know, INFORMATION_SCHEMA has been obsolete already.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I just thought that most of SQL-compliant DBMS provide it.

Comment: You can query from dictionary to see the whole data dictionary `select * from dictionary`

Answer (score 0):

In case you mean foreign key constraints, you can use the following query:

```
select a.table_name "PARENT", b.table_name "CHILD"
  from user_constraints a, user_constraints b
  where a.constraint_type = 'P'
    and b.constraint_type = 'R'
    and a.constraint_name = b.r_constraint_name;
```